# Unable to run SonarQube on AWS EKS with Fargate

Tags: sonarqube, amazon-ecs, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I'm trying to run the SonarQube on AWS EKS using the Fargate profile (serverless) but SonarQube is getting stopped every time with the below logs:-

```
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro sonar % kubectl logs sonarqube -f
2021.02.27 07:01:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2021.02.27 07:01:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:42201]
2021.02.27 07:01:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2021.02.27 07:01:07 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[7.9.3], pid[41], build[oss/tar/c4138e51121ef06a6404866cddc601906fe5c868/2020-10-16T10:36:16.141335Z], OS[Linux/4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64/amd64], JVM[AdoptOpenJDK/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/11.0.8/11.0.8+10]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM home [/opt/java/openjdk]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp, -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT, -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true, -Xmx512m, -Xms512m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es, -Des.distribution.flavor=oss, -Des.distribution.type=tar, -Des.bundled_jdk=false]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (127.0.0.1:/)]], net usable_space [8191.9pb], net total_space [8191.9pb], types [nfs4]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2021.02.27 07:01:10 WARN  es[][o.e.d.c.s.Settings] [node.master] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.
2021.02.27 07:01:10 WARN  es[][o.e.d.c.s.Settings] [node.data] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version.
2021.02.27 07:01:11 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [gGeLsF2zR66YuxVjyENzkA], cluster name [sonarqube]
2021.02.27 07:01:13 WARN  es[][o.e.d.c.r.OperationRouting] searches will not be routed based on awareness attributes starting in version 8.0.0; to opt into this behaviour now please set the system property [es.search.ignore_awareness_attributes] to [true]
2021.02.27 07:01:14 INFO  es[][o.e.t.NettyAllocator] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=false, g1gc_enabled=false, g1gc_region_size=0b, heap_size=494.9mb}]
2021.02.27 07:01:14 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
2021.02.27 07:01:14 WARN  es[][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:42201}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:42201}
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] explicitly enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max number of threads [1024] for user [sonarqube] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /opt/sonarqube/logs/sonarqube.log
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
2021.02.27 07:01:15 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 78
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2021.02.27 07:01:15 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

This is my Pod definition file:-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
  name: sonarqube
  namespace: cicd
spec:
  containers:
        - name: sonarqube
          image: sonarqube:8.6.1-community
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 4
              memory: "20Gi"
            #limits:
              #cpu: 6000m
              #memory: 2048Mi
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/data/"
            name: sonar-data
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/extensions/"
            name: sonar-extensions
          env:
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME"
            valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: configuration
               key: USERNAME
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL"
            valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: configuration
               key: URL
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD"
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: db-password
                key: password
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
            protocol: TCP
  volumes:
  - name: sonar-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: claim-sonar-data
  - name: sonar-extensions
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: claim-sonar-extensions
```

If I increase the CPU resource limit on this same Pod to 5 then I get the below issue:-

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  7m39s  fargate-scheduler  Your pod's cpu/memory requirements exceed the max Fargate configuration
```

Not sure if there is any limitation or SonarQube requires high CPU/Memory utilization and/or can only be run on dedicated Virtual Machines like EC2 backed EKS cluster and not Fargate.
Please advise why my SonarQube is not running serverless on EKS with Fargate profile.

Update:-

Tried adding the environment variables but all in vain, please advise, thanks:-

```
spec:
  #securityContext:
   #fsGroup: 999
  containers:
        - name: sonarqube
          #image: sonarqube:8.6.1-community
          #image: sonarqube:7.9-community
          image: sonarqube:latest
          #command: ["-Dsonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false"]
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 4
              memory: "25Gi"
            #limits:
              #cpu: 6000m
              #memory: 2048Mi
          volumeMounts:
          #- mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/conf/"
            #name: sonarqube-conf
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/data/"
            name: sonar-data
          - mountPath: "/opt/sonarqube/extensions/"
            name: sonar-extensions
          env:
          - name: sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts
            value: -Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false
          #- name: sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts
            #value: -Dnode.store.allow_mmapfs=false
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME"
            valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: configuration
               key: USERNAME
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL"
            valueFrom:
             configMapKeyRef:
               name: configuration
               key: URL
          - name: "SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD"
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: db-password
                key: password
          ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
            protocol: TCP
```

Any idea as Im still stuck with this issue?

Comment: `[1]: max number of threads [1024] for user [sonarqube] is too low, increase to at least [4096]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]` The error is in the logs

Comment: Yes, but how to fix it. I tried passing the enviornment variables and tried all the things like below:-   containers:
        - name: sonarqube
          image: sonarqube:latest
          #command: ["-Dsonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false"]
          env:
          - name: sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts
            value: -Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false
          #- name: sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts
            #value: -Dnode.store.allow_mmapfs=false

Comment: @vinod827 Please follow this link https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/

Comment: I tried my hard and stuck since yesterday. Till now trying to resolve this issue from morning....no idea. I used init containers like this but nothing is working. Please assist if you can, thanks  spec:
  #securityContext:
   #fsGroup: 999
  initContainers:
  - name: sysctl
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    securityContext:
      privileged: true      
    command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]

Comment: Any idea on the root cause?

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: no @chathux , volumes are not supported when it comes to serverless Fargate technology as SonarQube has to write to volumes using the readWriteMany principle...so I had to change my AWS EKS cluster to nodegroup based (VM backed) from Fargate....

Comment: Even I am facing the similar issue. Using EFS CSI driver with RWX permissions. But no fate. Looking for more hints

Comment: @NitinGarg...I had changed the cluster to nodegroup than Fargate because EFS does not support it. With nodegroup, atleast you can run this sonarqube successfully and persist the data on host volumes i.e. EBS